# My http post to a site send me to error page with 302 redirect?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I do login to a site using httpwebreq in C#, post to webpage. All works fine but at a specific URL it sends me to an error page with 302 redirect. Is there any way in Visual Studio to get the exact reason of 302 redirect at that URL?

What I have tried:

1. I have tried to make same request as browser do on that URL.
2. Send all header AS browser do.

Is it possible to get reason of redirect in Visual Studio, or how may I know why I am being redirected. Please share your knowledge on this, I am new at this.

Comment: Please send yours currently code sample.

Comment: Download for free a sniffer like fiddler.  fiddler will give you more diagnostics.

Comment: hi jiri , code block is too big, please send me your email , i will share with you